# Adding videos to application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, video

I want to store large number of videos in my application's directory. Will it make my application slow? Or will it take time to launch the application. I am loading videos only when necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will make large size of your application which is not good...& it will also take time to launch in place of save all ur video u can make user to download that video from server and after that it will be saved in ur doc directory so ur app will be not of large size.............

Answer (score 0):

Where is it located locally

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"videoname" ofType:@"mov" inDirectory:@""]];
```

and play with that

```
 MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
 [[player view] setFrame:[self.view bounds]]; // Frame must match parent view
 [self.view addSubview:[player view]];
 [player play];
 [player release];
```

**EDIT:-**

The exact answer to this question is NO, it will not make your App Slow,But yeah it ill take some time to load the videos in your App,Time will depend upon number of videos you are loading in your APP. The solution to this is you have to use blocks for ALAssetLibaries.

Have a look on this [ALAssetLibary Apple's class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

It may help you if not do contact me. Thanks :)